# Auth::check() not working with subdomains

Tags: angularjs, laravel-4

I have my AngularJS frontend at `app.example.dev` and my Laravel API backend at `api.example.dev`. `app.example.dev` makes a call to `api.example.dev/login` which logs a user in using `Auth::attempt($userdata, true)`. This works just fine, and returns true if the credentials match up. However, the login data does not persist.

When I make a call to `Auth::check()`, it always returns false.

What I have tried:

- Passed `true` as the second argument to `Auth::attempt()`
- Added `'domain' => '.example.dev'` to `app/config/session.php`
- Made sure `id` is the primary key for my `Users` model

I am running this setup on an Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine with Windows 8 as the host OS. I have edited my `/etc/hosts` file so both domains/sub-domains point to 127.0.0.1 (if that matters).

Some relevant code ...

```
#app/routes.php
...
Route::get('checkLogin', 'AuthController@checkLogin');
Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login')->before('guest');
...

#app/controllers/AuthController.php
...
public function checkLogin() {
    if(Auth::check()) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'loggedIn' => true,
            'roleId' => Auth::user()->role_id,
            'username' => Auth::user()->username));
            // 'id' => Auth::id()));
    } else {
        return Response::json(array(
            'loggedIn' => false));
    }
}
...
public function login() {
    $userdata = array(
        'username' => Input::get('username'),
        'password' => Input::get('password')
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($userdata, true)) {
        return Response::json(array(
            'loggedIn' => true,
            'roleId' => Auth::user()->role_id,
            'username' => Auth::user()->username));
    } else {
        return Response::json(array('loggedIn' => false));
    }
}
```

And in AngularJS I just have a service set up which calls these routes, ex:

```
...
var login = function(credentials) {
    return $http.post(apiUrl+'login', credentials);
}
...
```

Comment: could you please post some code

Comment: I have added some code.